# respond_with - How to respond with a text

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the respond_to and respond_with in a rails app, but in one use case I need to respond with just a text for just one of the resource formats (:json)... But I can't find how to do this...

I want something like this (I know this doesn't work)

```
def create
    ...
    respond_with(:json, render :text => "Successfully Done!")
end
```

Any Idea??

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems that this may be what you are looking for:

```
def create
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render :text => "Successfully Done!" }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 10):

Andres,

The solution is this:

```
class TextController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json, :text

  def index
    respond_with do |format|
      format.json {
        render :text => "I'm a text provided by json format"
      }
      format.text {
        render :text => "I'm a text"
      }
    end
  end
end
```

And at your routes.rb:

```
match '/text' => 'text#index', defaults: { format: 'text' }
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be: "format.json" since he wants to respond with text to a json request?

Comment: I did this! respond_with do |format|format.json{ render :text=> "Done"} end ... It was not necessary to add the route... Thanks bruno!

Comment: @Andres, with the route declared you adds a constraint if this action is called by the browser. For example, if you create a robots.txt dynamically and someone call the robots.txt's action at browser by default Rails interprets as html format's call. `Started GET "/text" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-10-09 14:40:51 -0300
Processing by TextController#index as HTML`